# How to disable the button(should not do anything) if either of input is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUBf8.png)
it shows Nan when there is no number, how can a disable it?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Try using an if statement to check if `num1` and `num2` are not empty before setting `res.value`

Answer (score 0):

Disable the buttons in html by adding a disabled attribute. Write an on-change handler for the inputs where the buttons are enabled only if there is value.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

```
const input1 = document.querySelector('#num1');
const input2 = document.querySelector('#num2');

input1.addEventListener('change', handleButton);
input2.addEventListener('change', handleButton);

function handleButton() {
  if(input1.value && input2.value) {
    document.querySelector(".button").removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".button").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

You can target the buttons by the classname which you have used. I have used .button in the answer.